# How to get the deals which are expiring today with MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, date

How do I get the today's deals only with deal_expiry_date_time is greater that current time?

```
SELECT *
FROM `deals` AS `d`
WHERE d.status = 'Active' AND d.deal_end_date_time BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 0 DAY)
AND d.created_by_id = '11'
ORDER BY `d`.`deal_id` ASC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: try like `d.deal_end_date_time >NOW();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if following sql is what you want or not, if you post some sample data and expected result, then we will understand your logic better.

```
SELECT *
FROM `deals` AS `d`
WHERE d.status = 'Active'
AND d.deal_end_date_time >= NOW()
AND DATE(d.deal_end_date_time) = CURRENT_DATE
AND d.created_by_id = '11'
ORDER BY `d`.`deal_id` ASC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Add round brackets -> `CURRENT_DATE()`

Answer (score 2):

To select everything from now to the end of the day

```
SELECT *
FROM `deals` AS `d`
WHERE d.status = 'Active'
AND d.deal_end_date_time BETWEEN NOW() AND CONCAT(CURDATE(), " 23:59:59")
AND d.created_by_id = '11'
ORDER BY `d`.`deal_id` ASC
LIMIT 5
```

To select everything from now to tomorrow

```
SELECT *
FROM `deals` AS `d`
WHERE d.status = 'Active'
AND d.deal_end_date_time BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
AND d.created_by_id = '11'
ORDER BY `d`.`deal_id` ASC
LIMIT 5
```

My suggestion is to have both datetime and date in your table to avoid loosing indexes filtering with funcs

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `deals` AS `d`
WHERE d.status = 'Active' AND CAST( d.deal_end_date_time AS date ) = CURRENT_DATE
AND d.created_by_id = '11'
ORDER BY `d`.`deal_id` ASC
LIMIT 5
```